# write to csv from dataframes using python panda

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

This is my csv file.

```
Uid,Message,Status
9425252526,Hello 1,0
9425252527,Hello 2,0
9425252528,Hello 3,0
9425252529,Hello 4,0
9425252530,Hello 5,0
```

if I convert it to pandas dataframe and write it back to another file,it adds this unwanted extra column as below (leftmost column)

```
,Uid,Message,Status
0,9425252526,Hello 1,0
1,9425252527,Hello 2,0
2,9425252528,Hello 3,0
3,9425252529,Hello 4,0
4,9425252530,Hello 5,0
```

How to remove this column ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you named your dataframe `df`.  You need to set the `index` to `false`:

```
df.to_csv("yourFile.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need add `index=False` to [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
print df.to_csv(index=False)

"Uid,Message,Status"
"9425252526,Hello 1,0"
"9425252527,Hello 2,0"
"9425252528,Hello 3,0"
"9425252529,Hello 4,0"
"9425252530,Hello 5,0"
```

Or with `filename`:

```
df.to_csv('filename', index=False)
```